# Multiple orderby based on this conditions in Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make my list in ASCENDING order based on the **menuCategory** which has the value "food" and "drink", then **menuName** which is also ASCENDING. And lastly, based on **menuPrice** from the cheapest to the most expensive.

```
when {
    userId != null -> {
        firebaseFirestore.collection("outlets").document(outletId)
            .collection("menu")
            .orderBy("menuCategory")
            .orderBy("menuName")
            .orderBy("menuPrice", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get()
            .apply {
                addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                    for (document in querySnapshot) {
                        document.apply {
                            menuList.add(
                                Menu(
                                    getString("menuCategory"),
                                    getString("menuPhoto"),
                                    getString("menuName"),
                                    getString("menuDescription"),
                                    getString("menuPrice")
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    adapter = menuOutletDetailAdapter
                    menuOutletDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But after I make code like above, the list doesn't appear. What kind of code do I have to make in order to make the list the way I want it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add an index, which is necessary when you order on multiple fields in a single query.

If you check the logcat output of your app, there should be a warning/error about this, which also includes **a direct link to the page where you can create the index, with all fields prepopulated for you**. If you can't find the error, you might want to add a failure callback and log it there.